# how to copy one column data to another column with in the same table using linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects, linq-to-dataset

any one please clarify,  how to copy one column data to another column with in the same table using linq.

Thank you,
Siva Kumar goru.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do that without LINQ (which purpose is quering data, not modifying)

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    row["AnotherColumn"] = row["OneColumn"];
```

Comment: How do I create the object 'table'?  I am using enityframework and sql server 2008. And then I will need to update it back to there server after doing the copy.